# Unable to spy on existing function

Tags: javascript, node.js, sinon, spy

I'm unable to spy on an existing function in the current scope within `node.js`:

```
function myFunc() {console.log("Spy on me and I'll have you arrested"};
sinon.spy(myFunc);
myFunc.restore(); // throws an error: myFunc.restore is not a function
```

I can however spy on a function which is a member of an object:

```
var anObject = {
  myFunc: function() {console.log('Being spied on turns me on');}
};
sinon.spy(anObject, 'myFunc');
sinon.myFunc.restore(); // smooth sailing
```

According to [the docs](http://sinonjs.org/docs/), it seems to me like that should work fine. How do I get this done?

Answer (score 1):

In JavaScript when a `function` is passed as an argument it is a reference-passed-by-value, like so:

```
function foo() { console.log("foo"); } // func1, referenced by `foo`
function bar() { console.log("bar"); } // func2, referenced by `bar`

function mutate(func) {
    func = bar;
}

mutate( foo );
foo();
```

This will print out `"foo"`, not `"bar"`, because `mutatate` does not change `foo`'s reference to `func1`.

Here is the relevant source code for Sinon's `spy.js`: https://github.com/sinonjs/sinon/blob/master/lib/sinon/spy.js

The `create` function sees if the first argument is a function, and if so, it wraps it in a proxy (`create: function create(func, spyLength) {`, line 148). It then returns the proxy.

So in your case, you need to replace `myFunc` with the new proxy:

```
function myFunc() {console.log("Spy on me and I'll have you arrested"};
myFunc = sinon.spy(myFunc); // here
```

However you cannot use `myFunc.restore()` to undo the spy because `.restore` cannot change the target of the `myFunc` reference. Note that `restore` also does not return a value, so you must keep track of `myFunc` yourself:

```
function myFuncOriginal() {console.log("Spy on me and I'll have you arrested"};
var myFunc = sinon.spy(myFuncOriginal);
myFunc = myFuncOriginal; // instead of `myFunc.restore();`
```

Comment: `restore` won't work here - the spy can't mutate the parent scope in that way (`restore` only works for the `spy(object, methodname)` constructor).

Comment: @SeanVieira Thanks, I've improved my answer.